# How to host multiple version of a Sphinx based documentation on GitHub?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When using Github pages to host Sphinx documentation, it might be desirable to host multiple versions of the same documentation for different branches or tag of the code.
However, both `sphinxcontrib-multiversion` and `sphinxcontrib-versioning` are not actively maintained and they do not work with the latest version of Sphinx.

If one does not want to use ReadTheDocs, and want to stick to the Alabaster theme, what would be the right solution ?

Answer (score 5):

For a DIY implementation, you can refer to how I implemented this for the [rinohtype documentation](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/). I first implemented this for the Sphinx RTD theme and later switched to Sphinx-Immaterial. Note that both of these themes provide version selectors, which I don't think Alabaster does.

These are the relevant commits:

- [GitHub workflow: publish docs to version dir](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/commit/8a23be41d39d748955b139f0fabefe3205a4fd93)
- [GitHub workflow: find docs versions and write to JSON](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/commit/6ba7637c248add1ce90efa7bb1c761d690b0de17)
- [HTML docs: populate Versions pane from JSON file](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/commit/1270802c4959eb4742c51d3307222930ac73a80c)
- [Docs: configure/create im_versions.json for Sphinx-Immaterial](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/commit/3885385c49dbb50dfb92ea8f0e0282ce291b1e21)